# Html tags renders but does't function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a div which renders on a boolean condition triggered by a button.
I have multiple select options in the new div. The problem is just the first  works and others dont.

Code Snippet:

```
var Results = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        partname:[],
        moveOptions: false,
        fromLocation:'',
        toLocation:'',
        moveQuantity:0
    }
},
componentWillMount:function(){
    var partInfo = [];
    var count = 0;
   //ajax calls to get partInfo
    this.setState({
        partInfo:partInfo
    });
},
showMoveOptions: function(){
    this.setState({moveOptions:!this.state.moveOptions});
},

movePart: function(){
    //ajax call
},
handleQuantityChange: function(e){
    this.setState({
        moveQuantity:e.target.value
    });
},
handleFromChange: function(e){
    this.setState({
        fromLocation:e.target.value
    });
},
handleToChange: function(e){
    this.setState({
        toLocation:e.target.value
    });
},

render: function() {
    var partInfo = this.state.partInfo;
    return(
        <div>
        <div id="results">
        <br/>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
                <h3>Part Name :{this.props.partname}</h3>
                <div className="container">
                  {
                        partInfo.map(function(l){
                        return([
                                <div>
                                         <h3>Building: {l.building}</h3>
                                         <h3>Location: {l.location}</h3>
                                         <h3>Quantity: {l.qty}</h3>
                                </div>
                            ]);
                        }.bind(this))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">        
                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.showMoveOptions()}>Move</button>

            </div>
        </div>
     { this.state.moveOptions ? 
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>From: </h3>
                            <select onChange={this.handleFromChange.bind(this)}>

                            partInfo.map(function(from){
                                    return(
                                            <option value={from.location}>{from.location}</option>
                                    )
                                }
                            </select><br/>
                        <h3>To: </h3> 
                            <select onChange={this.handleToChange.bind(this)} >

                                partInfo.map(function(to){
                                    return(
                                            <option value={to.location}>{to.location}</option>
                                    )
                                }
                            </select><br/>

                        <h3>Quantity:</h3>
                        <input type="text" name="quantity" value={this.state.moveQuantity} onChange={this.handleQuantityChange.bind(this)}/>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.movePart()}>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>  : null
                }
                </div>
            );
        }
```

});

As shown in the code the first select tag works. After that all tags are rendered but i neither can select the drop down menu nor i can change text in input tag.

Comment: bind your onChange Handler... For clear answer, show your full component..

Comment: @FazalRasel doing something like onChange={this.handleFromChange.bind(this)} is not helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle `onChange` event to update *controlled* `input`.

Check the documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

> A **controlled** `<input>` has a `value` prop. Rendering a controlled `<input>` will reflect the value of the `value` prop.

and

> User input will have no effect on the rendered element

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/60429/) with your code. You have lost some brackets in your snippet, and you should not bind handlers to `this` when using `React.createClass` syntax. But the rest is working just fine.

Comment: i am hadling the user input by onChange event @cyberskunk

Comment: I've added the link to live fiddle, where your code just works (after fixing several syntax errors/typos and adding two dummy elements to `partInfo` to test the example).